# Conditional DataFrame filter on boolean columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

If I have a DataFrame as so:

```
| id     | attribute_1 | attribute_2 |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
| 123abc | TRUE        | TRUE        |
| 123abc | TRUE        | FALSE       |
| 456def | TRUE        | FALSE       |
| 789ghi | TRUE        | TRUE        |
| 789ghi | FALSE       | FALSE       |
| 789ghi | FALSE       | FALSE       |
```

How do I apply a `groupby` or some equivalent filter to count the unique number of `id` elements in a subset of the DataFrame that looks like this:

```
| id     | attribute_1 | attribute_2 |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
| 123abc | TRUE        | TRUE        |
| 123abc | TRUE        | FALSE       |
```

Meaning, I want to get the unique number of `id` values where `attribute_1 == True` *for all instances of a given `id`* BUT `attribute_2` must have at least 1 `True`.

So, `456def` would not be included in the filter because it does not have at least one `True` for `attribute_2`.

`789ghi` would not be included in the filter because all of it's `attribute_1` entries are not `True`.

Comment: @jpp "all of it's attribute_1 entries". Meaning `789ghi` must have `True` for each instance of `attribute_1` but at least one `True` for `attribute_2`

Comment: OK, I've updated wording in your question, feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @jpp looks great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `groupby` twice, once with `transform('all')` on "attribute_1" and the second time with `transform('any')` on "attribute_2".

```
i = df[df.groupby('id').attribute_1.transform('all')]
j = i[i.groupby('id').attribute_2.transform('any')]

print (j)
       id  attribute_1  attribute_2
0  123abc         True         True
1  123abc         True        False
```

Finally, to get the unique IDs that satisfy this condition, call `nunique`:

```
print (j['id'].nunique())
1
```

This is easiest to do when your attribute_* columns are boolean. If they are strings, fix them first:

```
df = df.replace({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
```